# JavaFX: Change CSS PseudoClass on Key Event

Tags: css, button, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a button which changes it`s design when it is clicked. (Per CSS) Easy.

But I also want to enable the function that if you press ENTER it should also be pressed. That works, but I have a pseudo-class which sets the size of the button to 90% (`.button:pressed`).

**Problem:** It doesn't work when the Enter key is pressed. The click works fine. Is there any css pseudo-class for KeyTyped?

**CSS:**

```
.button{
        -fx-background-image: url("../resources/Game/cookie.png");
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.button:pressed{
    -fx-background-size: 90%;
    -fx-background-position: center;
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly add the pseudo-class "**pressed**" when Enter is pressed and then remove it when it is released.

```
button.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
   if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
      button.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pressed"), true);
   }
});

button.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
   if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
      button.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pressed"), false);
   }
});
```

---

### MCVE

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button("Change Color");
        button.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                button.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pressed"), true);
            }
        });

        button.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                button.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pressed"), false);
            }
        });
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 200, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("test.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

**test.css**

```
.button:pressed{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```